# Guardar array en diferentes campos mysql con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array, mysqli

Acudo nuevamente a la comunidad porque no he conseguido esto, ya he probado con for y con foreach sin lograr el resultado esperado.

El asunto es así, tengo un archivo txt que lo convierto a un array mediante explode, hasta allí, todo bien, pero ahora necesito guardar los datos en campos diferentes de la siguiente forma, esta es la estructura del contenido del archivo:

> 2018-09-29 ‪|+58 412-4860299‬ |Necesito de un apto para alquiler de 3 habitaciones, amueblado y equipado.
>   |2018-09-29 ‪|+58 414-4166002‬ |Buenos días.
>   SKY Group vende apartamento en Tulipán planta baja, piso porcelanato, bella cocina semi equipada, clóset modular madera, sin hipoteca, torre bien cuidada con caico y grafiadas en paredes áreas comunes. Ref. 9500 negociable 
>   Peggy Araujo
>   04144166002
>   |2018-09-29 ‪|+58 414-4166002‬ |Nueva captacion
>   SKY Group vende en la Isabelica planta baja 3h1b cocina en mampostería, paredes y techos encaminadas en cuartos dos de ellos con closets empotrados, baño en cerámica conservado, porche al frente y terreno para futura ampliación dejan tanque de 2500litros con bomba. Ref. 4800 
>   Apártamento Isabelica 1er piso remodelado y actualizado, cableado y tuberías nuevas, 3 habítaciones con closets empotrados, baño de lujo con pareduche vidrio templado y piezas sanitarias importadas, griferías BM, bella cocina con base en mármol travertino, tope y salpicadero en porcelanato con sillas modernas, área de lavandería, totalmente encaminadas paredes y techos, una pared en espacato, todo el piso en porcelanato de primera, posee línea telefónica, Internet gas directo, dejan lámparas importadas en todas las áreas que combinan, repisas minimalista, calentador de agua, bomba 3/4, aire acondicionado, edificio bien conservado y céntrico.  Ref.6350 negociable. Pase su propuesta.
>   Peggy Araujo
>   04144166002
>   |2018-09-29 ‪|+58 412-4805610‬ |SKY GROUP Vende apartamento ubicado en San Diego específicamente en Res. San Francisco, consta de:
>    73mts2
>    3 habitaciones
>    2 baños
>    2 P/E lineal descubierto,
>    Piso medio
>    Condición a estrenar
>    Queda con las cerámicas del piso y baño listas para colocar, paredes y techos ya encamisados y pintados.
>   El conjunto cuenta con pozo de agua propio, gas directo, planta eléctrica, vigilancia privada, piscina, área de caney, ascensor la zona es bastante tranquila y en amplio crecimiento.
>   CÓDIGO: SDA-443
>   *Precio de venta 11.000*
>   Luis Alejandro Alvarez
>   Asesor inmobiliario *Sky Group*
>   0412-4805610

El código que utilizo para convertir el archivo txt es éste, sencillo:

> $array = explode("|", file_get_contents('prueba.txt'));

Y el array que obtengo, es más o menos así:

> array(63) { [0]=> string(14) "2018-09-29 ‪" [1]=> string(19) "+58 412-4860299‬ " [2]=> string(76) "Necesito de un apto para alquiler de 3 habitaciones, amueblado y equipado. " [3]=> string(14) "2018-09-29 ‪" [4]=> string(19) "+58 414-4166002‬ " [5]=> string(286) "Buenos días. SKY Group vende apartamento en Tulipán planta baja, piso porcelanato, bella cocina semi equipada, clóset modular madera, sin hipoteca, torre bien cuidada con caico y grafiadas en paredes áreas comunes. Ref. 9500 negociable  Peggy Araujo 04144166002 " [6]=> string(14) "2018-09-29 ‪" [7]=> string(19) "+58 414-4166002‬ " [8]=> string(1059) "Nueva captacion SKY Group vende en la Isabelica planta baja 3h1b cocina en mampostería, paredes y techos encaminadas en cuartos dos de ellos con closets empotrados, baño en cerámica conservado, porche al frente y terreno para futura ampliación dejan tanque de 2500litros con bomba. Ref. 4800  Apártamento Isabelica 1er piso remodelado y actualizado, cableado y tuberías nuevas, 3 habítaciones con closets empotrados, baño de lujo con pareduche vidrio templado y piezas sanitarias importadas, griferías BM, bella cocina con base en mármol travertino, tope y salpicadero en porcelanato con sillas modernas, área de lavandería, totalmente encaminadas paredes y techos, una pared en espacato, todo el piso en porcelanato de primera, posee línea telefónica, Internet gas directo, dejan lámparas importadas en todas las áreas que combinan, repisas minimalista, calentador de agua, bomba 3/4, aire acondicionado, edificio bien conservado y céntrico.  Ref.6350 negociable. Pase su propuesta. Peggy Araujo 04144166002 " [9]=> string(14) "2018-09-29 ‪" [10]=> string(19) "+58 412-4805610‬ " [11]=> string(664) "SKY GROUP Vende apartamento ubicado en San Diego específicamente en Res. San Francisco, consta de:  73mts2  3 habitaciones  2 baños  2 P/E lineal descubierto,  Piso medio  Condición a estrenar  Queda con las cerámicas del piso y baño listas para colocar, paredes y techos ya encamisados y pintados. El conjunto cuenta con pozo de agua propio, gas directo, planta eléctrica, vigilancia privada, piscina, área de caney, ascensor la zona es bastante tranquila y en amplio crecimiento. CÓDIGO: SDA-443 *Precio de venta 11.000* Luis Alejandro Alvarez Asesor inmobiliario *Sky Group* 0412-4805610 "

Lo que necesito, es que las claves 0, 3, 6, 9, 12 y así sucesivamente se guarden en el campo de mi tabla fecha.

Ésto lo puedo lograr con un bucle for

> $conteo = count ($array);
>   for ($i=0; $iquery("INSER INTO prueba(fecha) 
>   VALUES('$array[$i]')");
>   }

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero el problema es que cuando ejecuto la sentencia para las siguientes claves, cambiando $i por 1 y 2 respectivamente, me crea una tabla donde desde el id 1 al 23 aparece la fecha, desde el id 24 al 46 me aparece la fecha 0000-00-00 y el contacto; luego del id 47 al 69 igual la fecha en 0000-00-00 y la descripción.

Lo que quiero es establecer una correlación donde las claves
0 + 3 hasta culminar el bucle de acuerdo a la cantidad de claves que obtengo con count se escriba desde el id 1 llenando el campo fecha.
Luego las claves 1 + 3 desde el id 1 llenando el campo contacto.
Luego las claves 2 + 3 desde el id 1 llenando el campo descripción.

Éste es mi código completo:

> include 'conexion.php';
>
> //Convertimos el txt en array $array = explode("|",
>   file_get_contents('prueba.txt'));
>
> //Contamos la cantidad de claves $conteo = count($array);
>
> for ($i=0; $i";
>
> }
>
> for ($i=1; $i";
>
> }
>
> for ($i=2; $i";
>
> }

Comment: No colocaste los incrementos en tu for en el código de muestra. Por otro lado lo que dices es un comportamiento raro en php. ¿Por que no usas un array_filter y una expresión regular?

Comment: No termino de entender lo que quieres hacer, pero leyéndote me pregunto una cosa, ¿los datos existen ya así en el archivo de texto sin más remedio o puedes generarlos de otra forma? Por ejemplo, puedes usar dos separadores, uno para cada grupo y uno para cada ítem, algo así: `Dato1Grupo1|Dato2Grupo1|Dato3Grupo1...¦Dato1Grupo2|Dato2Grupo2|Dato3Grupo2...` así haces dos `explode` primero por `¦` para cada grupo y luego por `|` para cada ítem y en seguida buscas las claves `0, 3, 6, 9, 12` en cada grupo sin más complicaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor que podrías hacer aquí es dividir el Array que obtienes del explode en Arrays de 3 (los datos de cada registro) con [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-chunk.php) , luego recorres con un foreach e insertas cada registro, algo asi:

```
//Convertimos el txt en array 
$array = explode("|", file_get_contents('prueba.txt'));
// Dividimos en bloques de 3
$data  = array_chunk($array, 3);

// Recorremos los registros
foreach($data as $value) {
    // Realizar insert 
    echo 'Fecha: '. $value[0].'<br>';
    echo 'Teléfono: '. $value[1].'<br>';
    echo 'Notas: '. $value[2].'<br>';
}
```

El insert seria todo en una sentencia por registro, o construir una sentencia única para todos los registros:

```
INSER INTO prueba(fecha, teléfono,  notas) VALUES('$value[0]', '$value[1]', '$value[2]')
```

Todo en un único insert

```
// Recorremos los registros
foreach($data as $value) {
    //creas los values del insert
    $r = implode (',', $value);
    $values[] = '('. $r .')';
}
// unes los values
$values = implode(',', $values);
// construyes la sentencia
$sql = 'INSER INTO prueba(fecha, teléfono,  notas) VALUES '. $values;
```

Como recomendación si los datos a insertar no son seguros(generalmente todos son inseguros hasta que se demuestre lo contrario), seria recomendable el uso de sentencias preparadas, en lugar de concatenar los valores.

Comment: Muchas gracias Xerif, si funcionó el código pero no fue necesario el implode, lo que hice fue lo siguiente en el foreach `INSERT INTO prueba(telefono, contacto, descripcion) VALUES ('$value[0]', '$value[1]', '$value[2]')` y listo hizo exactamente lo que quería. De verdad muchas gracias, no se me había ocurrido hacer el array_chunk. Muchísimas, gracias.